# Grails get controller parameters

Tags: grails, parameters, controller

I do an AJAX request with some data. I pass a list (for example, [6, 9]). When I print all parameters

```
println params
```

in controller, I get:

```
[books[]:[6, 9], action:someAction, controller:someController]
```

but when I do

```
println params.books
```

I get `null`. Why??
Who can I get [6, 9] as a result.

P.S I am using grails 2.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, you don't have `books` key, but `books[]` instead.

So you have to use:

```
println params['books[]']
```